# Can I boot a LiveOS which stored on disk and install itself to disk with '--format' option?

Tags: kernel, boot, grub2, livecd

I made a LiveOS(live.iso) by `livemedia-creator` and put it in `/dev/sda1`. I modified grub.cfg, added a new entry and successfully boot into this LiveOS. Now I want to install this LiveOS to the disk `/dev/sda` by `livecd-iso-to-disk` with `--format`  option. However, the /dev/sda1 is mounted or busy. I wanna know is it possible? Or could anyone give me some advice please?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: It might be possible, for example if there is enough RAM to keep the whole live OS in RAM, but I would strongly recommend that you use a separate drive, for example a USB pendrive, and run your live system from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: May I ask why 'strongly recommend to use a separate drive'? What is the risk?

Comment: If something goes wrong during the installation, nothing will work, not the live system and not the installed system. Of course, if you have everything necessary in some other computer and can easily copy things over again, fine, but I have discussed this same issue with people who depend of one single computer, and for that reason I suggest to use booting the live system from a separate drive. (If enough RAM, you can use the boot option `toram` to copy the live system to RAM and then unmount the internal drive and then run the installer, but be warned ...)